# check if textdates in buttons are the same in onClickListener

Tags: java, android, date, button

I have two date buttons. These two buttons contains a String as text.
If someone clicks on the button a datepicker appears. After this datepicker
I want to check if the two buttons contains the same datestring.
If so, I want to let two buttons appear (below these two buttons) with two
timepickers.

[image: First image when no date is choosen]

[image: This is what should happen]

The problem is, the method which checks if the two dates are equal, automatically starts at first after clicking the button. So I have to click the button twice to properly check if the dates are equal.

Here's my code:

First the onClickListeners

```
startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        DateDialog dateStart = new DateDialog(startDate, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        checkdates();

    }
});

endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DateDialog dateEnd = new DateDialog(endDate, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        checkdates();
    }
});
```

Second, the checkdates method:

```
private void checkdates() {

    String firstdate = startDate.getText().toString();
    String seconddate = endDate.getText().toString();

    if (firstdate.equals(seconddate)) {
        row1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        row2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        row1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        row2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And at last, the Class DateDialog which is called in the onClickListener:

```
public class DateDialog {

private int mMonth;
private int mYear;
private int mDay;
private Button txtButton;

public DateDialog(Button b, int year, int month, int day){
    txtButton = b;
    onCreateDialog(year, month, day);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int year, int month, int day) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(NostradamusActivity2.parentcontext, mDateSetListener, year,
                month, day);
        dialog.show();
        return null;
}

// updates the date we display in the TextView
private void updateDisplay() {
    txtButton.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mYear).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mDay).append(""));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};
 }
```

Comment: how do you dismiss or confirm dialog?

Comment: I guess this is a build in function in the DatePickerDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `interface` inside `DateDialog` class like this:

```
public static interface DateDialogListener
{
     public void dialogDateChanged();
}
```

and declare a field inside `DateDialog` class as

```
DateDialogListener dateListener;
```

and create a `setter` method for it also.

and in `updateDisplay()` put this call at the end also

```
if(dateListener != null)
dateListener.dialogDateChanged();
```

and when you open a dialog from button `onClick()` inside `Activity` use `DateDialogListener` like this way:

```
DateDialog dateStart = new DateDialog(startDate, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
dateStart.setDateListener( new DateDialogListener()
{
     public void dialogDateChanged()
     {
         checkdates(); 
     }     
});
```

Comment: thanks, you were right about the double pop-up. I'm going to try your approach!